# Share bandwidth equally

Tags: networking, tc, traffic-shaping

I have a server with 100 Mbps bandwidth.

Clients with dynamic IPs could connect to web server and download large files

There are maximum **10 clients** which can download simultaneously

And I guarantee 10 Mbps bandwidth for each client

I need to use `tc` to allow them to use all bandwidth when they're dowloading alone or share bandwidth equally when downloading clients > 1

Never before worked with `tc`

I came up with :

```
tc qdisc del root dev ens3 default 10
tc qdisc add dev ens3 root handle 1: htb rate 100mbps
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10mbps ceil 90mbps
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10mbps ceil 90mbps
```

But when two clients start downloading then they share 10mbps bandwidth

I need when

```
1 client - max 100 Mbps
2 clients - max 50 Mbps each
3 clients - max 33 Mbps each
4 clients - max 25 Mbps each
...
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no trivial solution.

As [the (old but as far as I know still relevant) manual](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/rules.html) states:

> ## § 8.5 Sharing/splitting bandwidth based on IP
>
> For many administrators this is the ideal method of dividing bandwidth amongst their users. Unfortunately, there is no easy solution, and it becomes increasingly complex with the number of machine sharing a network link.
>
> To divide bandwidth equitably between N IP addresses, there must be N classes.

Comment: @hbruijnif I ended up writing a script that monitors the number of IPs on port 3000, creates classes based on the number of IPs and assigns each IP to a separate class. **1** `tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:$id htb rate ${SPEED[IPS_SIZE]}Mbit ceil ${SPEED[IPS_SIZE]}Mbit` **2** `tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst $ip flowid 1:$id` Is it an ok solution? Seems working as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
# Remove existing qdisc
tc qdisc del root dev ens3

# Set up new qdisc with HTB
tc qdisc add dev ens3 root handle 1: htb default 10

# Define root class
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps

# Define class for single client
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for two clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 50mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for three clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 33mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for four clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:40 htb rate 25mbps ceil 100mbps

# Add SFQ qdisc for each class
tc qdisc add dev ens3 parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev ens3 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev ens3 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev ens3 parent 1:40 handle 40: sfq perturb 10
```

This script sets up a hierarchical structure where each class corresponds to a different number of clients, and their bandwidth is limited accordingly. The sfq qdisc is used to provide fair queuing within each class.

And so for 10

```
# ... (previous configuration)

# Define class for five clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:50 htb rate 20mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for six clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:60 htb rate 16.67mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for seven clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:70 htb rate 14.29mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for eight clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:80 htb rate 12.5mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for nine clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:90 htb rate 11.11mbps ceil 100mbps

# Define class for ten clients
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:100 htb rate 10mbps ceil 100mbps

# ... (add SFQ qdisc for each new class)
```

Comment: If there are 10 clients all of them share 10mbps. They don't have 10mbps each. Is this expected behavior?